# No errors logged for Serilog SQL server sink logging

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, serilog

I have configured Serilog SQL server sink for my ASP.Net Core 2.2 web application based on the [documentation](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver). Neither the Logs table get created nor are any errors logged. What am I missing?

**AppSettings.Development.json:**

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "SQLServerConnectionString": "<ActualDataBaseConnectionString>"
  },
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer" ],
    "MinimumLevel": "Information",
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "MSSqlServer",
        "Args": {
          "connectionString": "SQLServerConnectionString",
          "tableName": "Logs",
          "autoCreateSqlTable": true 
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Program.cs:**

```
public class Program
  {
    private static string _environmentName;

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      try
      {
        var iWebHost = CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build();
        var path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
          .SetBasePath(path)
          .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
          .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{_environmentName}.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        .Build();

     var serilog = new Serilog();
        configuration.GetSection("Serilog").Bind(serilog);

        var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
          .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(serilog.WriteTo[0].Args.connectionString, serilog.WriteTo[0].Args.tableName)
          .ReadFrom.AppSettings()
          .CreateLogger();

        Log.Logger = logger;
        Log.Information("Application starting");
        iWebHost.Run();
      }
      catch(Exception exception)
      {
        Log.Error(exception.ToString());
      }
      finally
      {
        Log.CloseAndFlush();
      }
    }

  public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)        
        .ConfigureLogging((webHostBuilderContext, iLoggingBuilder) =>
        {
          iLoggingBuilder.AddSerilog();
          _environmentName = webHostBuilderContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName;
        })
        .UseStartup<Startup>();
  }

  public class Args
  {
    public string connectionString { get; set; }
    public string tableName { get; set; }
    public bool autoCreateSqlTable { get; set; }
  }

  public class WriteTo
  {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Args Args { get; set; }
  }

  public class Serilog
  {
    public List<string> Using { get; set; }
    public string MinimumLevel { get; set; }
    public List<WriteTo> WriteTo { get; set; }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end it was pretty straight foward. No changes were needed in my Program.cs file, I just had to configure the AppSettings.json.

**Program.cs:**

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      try
      {
        var iWebHost = CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build();
        var path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
          .SetBasePath(path)
          .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
          .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{_environmentName}.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        .Build();

        var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
          .Enrich.FromLogContext()
          .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
          .CreateLogger();

        Log.Logger = logger;
        Log.Information("Application starting");
        iWebHost.Run();
      }
      catch(Exception exception)
      {
        Log.Error(exception.ToString());
      }
      finally
      {
        Log.CloseAndFlush();
      }
    }
```

**AppSettings.development.json:**

```
{
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer" ],
    "MinimumLevel": "Information",
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "MSSqlServer",
        "Args": {
          "connectionString": "<DatabaseConnectionString>",
          "tableName": "Logs",
          "autoCreateSqlTable": true 
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```